# Scantokens and Let

Tags: catcodes

The package `inputenc` makes it possible, for example, to write `°` to print a degree symbol. Simplifying a bit, it obtains that by making it an active character (catcode 13) and defining the corresponding macro. If its category is changed to other (catcode 12) and, then, changed back with `\scantokens`, it keeps printing the degree symbol.
Since I need to print a string, a character at a time, spaces included, my first idea was of using `\let`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

A°@ 1

{\catcode`\°12 \xdef\str{A°@ 1}}
\str

\scantokens\expandafter{\str\empty}

\def\aaa{\afterassignment\bbb\let\ccc= }
\def\bbb{%
  \ifx\ccc\nil
     END
     \let\next\relax
  \else
     [\scantokens\expandafter{\ccc\empty}]\let\next\aaa
  \fi
  \next
}
\expandafter\aaa\str\nil

\end{document}
```

whose output is:

[image: Output first example]

Unfortunately, as jfbu pointed out, `\scantokens` does nothing on the `\let` character and so it prints `[ř]` instead of `[°]`. To make it apparent, consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

{\catcode`\°12 \gdef\ddd{°} \global\let\eee°}

[\ddd] - [\scantokens\expandafter{\ddd\empty}]

[\eee] - [\scantokens\expandafter{\eee\empty}]

\end{document}
```

whose output is:

[image: Output second example]

Of course, in the first example, one possible solution would be to substitute the `\scantokens` in square brackets with `\ifx\ccc\ddd°\else\ccc\fi`, having taken care to add `` {\catcode`\°12 \global\let\ddd°} `` at the beginning. The problem with this approach is that it is not very 'scalable'.

My real goal here is to parse some (CP-1252 encoded) files, which can contain any characters, not just `°`. To put this in context and for the sake of simplicity, let us just suppose I am coding a hex viewer in (La)TeX (which, by the way, would not be such a bad idea).

So, for the textual part, I first 'load' the file with something like `\edef\fff#1{\pdfunescapehex{\pdffiledump length \pdffilesize{#1}{#1}}}`, which gives all character tokens with catcode 12, except the space (that has catcode 10); then I scan such a token list and act as needed, printing it or else.

So, is there a way to scan a token list, including spaces, without using `\let`? Assigning catcode 12 also to spaces would suffice, can I do it? How? Alternatively, is there a way of changing the catcode after a `\let`, which does not involve a lot of conditional expressions? If not, what would be the best (compact and/or elegant) way to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Are you taking into account that `°` is not a single token?

Comment: @Manuel it is a single token in `ansinew` (cp1252` input encoding. This is not `utf8`.

Comment: while Manuel's comment isn't strictly accurate note your code here os very fragile, no new documents should be using `[ansinew]` (which doesn't refer to any standard encoding) if the encoding of the text changes (for example as posted above it is in UTF-8) then the code will fail as ° may be multiple tokens.

Comment: Thank you all for replying so quickly. I am trying to parse some CP-1252 encoded files (which is just an 8-bit extension of ASCII), that is why I am not using UTF-8 here; the code above is just a minimal example.

Comment: The `\edef` in `\edef\fff#1{... \pdffiledump ... {#1}{#1}}` can not work. Either you use `\def` with `#1` or you use `\edef` with for example `\jobname.tex` in place of `#1`.

Answer (score 6):

When you do the `\let\ccc=` it will "let" `\ccc` stand for successive tokens, and they all happen to be non-expandable actually in your `\str` macro contents. So the `\expandafter{\ccc` does nothing. And then the `\scantokens` does nothing either as it sees `\ccc`, it does not see the `°` token. By the way, you don't need `\xdef` for your `\str` definition, as there is nothing to expand as you have assigned `\catcode12` to `°` (in cp1252 code page, char code is 176 and this gives the `ř` in T1 font encoding.)

[image]

---

After update to original question. But it still isn't quite clear to me what is exactly the context. Here is how one can parse char per char, which is easy as everything but spaces is catcode 12. What I would do is to define macros `\@namedef{mymeaning<char>}` for special things (where `<char>` is one catcode 12 token, and perhaps use `\ifdefined`, and the others `\scantokens` can be used generally. Here I use `\meaning` and I separated backslash and percent because `\scantokens` on the char is no good then.

This is 8bit encoding ONLY method. I illustrate with `iso-latin-1`. Besides there are no `\par` token due to the `\pdffiledump` method.

And the file uses unix line endings.

```
% -*- coding:iso-latin-1; -*-
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\def\ParsePerWord #1 {\ifx\ignorespaces#1\ignorespaces
                         <SPACE>\par
                         \expandafter\ParsePerWord
                      \else
                         \if\relax#1\else
                            \ParsePerChar #1\relax
                            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ParsePerWord
                         \fi
                      \fi}
\def\ParsePerChar #1{\if\relax#1\bigskip % end of "word"
                     \else
                        \ifnum`#1=10 % unix end of line
                          <EOL>\par
                        \else
                          \ifnum`#1=92 % backslash
                             <BACKSLASH>\par
                          \else
                             \ifnum`#1=37 % percent
                                 <PERCENT>\par
                             \else
                                 \scantokens{\meaning #1}\par
                             \fi
                          \fi
                        \fi
                        \expandafter\ParsePerChar
                      \fi}

\begin{document}

éà°§ù"£{$\Omega$}\def\x#1{&}

\edef\fff{\pdfunescapehex{\pdffiledump offset 1198 length 100{\jobname.tex}}}

\show\fff

\ttfamily

\makeatletter
\@firstofone{\@firstofone{\expandafter\ParsePerWord\fff} \relax} %

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In the above, some spaces (those delimiting a "word") are rendered via a `\bigskip` and others (spaces at start of lines for example) by `<SPACE>\par`.

It might be better to do the following

```
\def\ParsePerWord #1 {\ifx\ignorespaces#1\ignorespaces
                         <SPACE>\par
                         \expandafter\ParsePerWord
                      \else
                         \if\relax#1%
                            <END OF DUMP>\par % <<-- CHANGED !
                         \else
                            \ParsePerChar #1\relax
                            <SPACE>\par %       <<-- CHANGED !
                            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ParsePerWord
                         \fi
                      \fi}
\def\ParsePerChar #1{\if\relax#1% end of "word" <<-- CHANGED !
                     \else
                     .... etc ....
```

which prints `<SPACE>\par` for all space characters from input. I also added an `<END OF DUMP>\par` (and removed the `\bigskip`).

But there is the problem that the last `<SPACE>` does not come from original, it is the one we added at end of `\fff` contents. There are various ways to get rid of it, but I don't know if the parsing loop is supposed to be expandable (so far, it is, it could be used in an `\edef`, if `\par` is let to `\relax` or prefixed by `\noexpand` to avoid special meanings it can have in a LaTeX document depending on location) so I leave it standing for now.

For example, here is output if `\fff` is set-up to contain the entire file.

[image]

This last `<SPACE>` does not come from the file contents but from our macro.

Remark: "ParsePerWord" is slightly misleading, because "words" may contain end-of-lines. To be closer to what text editors call words, we should presumably first "ParsePerLine" using not a space but a `^^J` delimiter.

Comment: So I gather the problem is using `\let` to scan my string. Therefore, is there a (possibly elegant) way to make it print a degree symbol in square brackets instead of `ř`? I know I could have used `\gdef` in place of `\xdef`.

Comment: with `\let` things become complicated, of course you could make a giant nested conditional with `256` `\ifx` to identify original token. Now it is not clear what is your context. In your mwe, I would simply define `\str` with the space being assigned catcode 12, then I would grab token by token (in the sense of `#1`) to build a macro with contents `[token1][token2 possibly ascii code 32]....etc...`, then I would apply  a unique `\scantokens` at the end to those contents (thus, with `\expandafter` once). I assume you don't have braces ?

Comment: I do have braces, but with catcode 12. I have expanded my question, including also some of your remarks, in the hope of making it clearer for everybody and to provide some context.

Comment: do I understand correctly that you want to parse cp1252 encoded non-TeX related files, from inside a TeX file, which may be or not cp1252 encoded itself ? because that point is still not clear to me. In my answers, the TeX file and the parsed file (which I took to be the `.tex` file itself) are encoded the same, so a `\scantokens` will most of the time "print" in PDF output the expected output. If the encodings differ, we have to do additional gymnastics. Then also, why use `\pdfunescapehex`, it might be simplerwith the hex encoded chars, we can define "cp1252-aware" macros from 2 hex letters.